# Is "Our creamiest coffee, now creamier" correct?

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree, degree-of-comparison

Kopiko's tagline here in the Philippines became a hot topic. Others had been saying that it is grammatically wrong but others said that it is correct.

Comment: Tell us why some say ut is grammatical, and why others argue the tagline is not. A link might be nice too.

Comment: They claim that is wrong because it is already in its superlative degree. But I think it is correct because of the context. I can't paste a link because I only have a screenshot picture.

Comment: @Jaredxx -  That’s not a grammatical problem, that’s a semantic problem.   But even at that,  it’s ***their*** creamiest not the creamiest possible.   Today’s best can be made better in the future.

Comment: Taglines are often non-grammatical, to keep them brief. Similar to headlines.

Comment: The tallest tree in my garden is now 2" talller it was a year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implied notion of time in the statement. Until now or recently this was our creamiest but our changes to it have made it creamier now. As a similar example, our tallest (until recently) daughter is even taller (today).

The key to understanding this grammatically is that in the superlative of yesterday is compared with the superlative of today. Hence, today’s best (superlative) is better (comparative) than yesterday’s best.

[British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives) : comparatives and superlatives.

Comment: It's presumably still the creamiest, unless at the same time they also made another product even creamier.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic problem. It could be phrased better with "even creamier". Instead of "now creamier" which sounds funny. Obviously either way it makes sense but phrasing could always be improved.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply advertising hyperbole.  Kinda like the Superbole we'll be having here in the US in about a month.

Comment: It should be called the Hyperbowl.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. As they are comparing their previous product that was creamiest. As they are comparing they used its comparative word which is "creamier".